# cordova run android executes fine. But Android 4.1.2 doesn't start the app

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, command-line-interface

I'm starting to develop and android app using Cordova 5.0.0 (cordova -v prints 5.0.0), and testing it on a Moto Razr D1 with Android 4.1.2.
Under Windows 7, btw.

```
cordova build
```

and manually copying the platforms/android/build/output/apk/android-degug.apk to the SD and installing works fine.

```
cordova emulate android
```

runs fine on emulator with android version >4.1.2

```
cordova run android
```

builds successfully, says using apk platforms/android/build/output/apk/android-debugger.apk, which seems ok,
installing app, launching and LAUNCH SUCCESS. however as you can see in this screenshot

[Razr Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeziP.jpg)

This "WALLPAPER/MANAGE/SETTINGS" thing happens, and that's it.

If I execute:

```
cordova emulate android
```

On an emulator with Android 4.1.2 Jelly, an equal output

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.352 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    C:\android\Some\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
Installing app on emulator...
Using apk: C:\android\Some\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

same "WALLPAPAER/MANAGE/SETTINGS", here's another screenshot [Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOQTr.jpg)

Any ideas how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance...

PS: If I've installed the apk previously, the Razr will startup the old version, instead of the WALLPAPER/MANAGE/SETTINGS thing. So I have to uninstall it before trying to run the cordova run commands.

Comment: Hey... me too I experienced the same problem. How is it now have you solved it out? @gerumato

Comment: Hi, Actually, I still didn't solve this. I'm using an Android 4.2.2 ADV emulator, and just installing  the android-debug.apk manually on the device.

Comment: manually? Waw... how could u debug the error...?  i mean,... for tracing the mistakes we've developed on code....

Comment: Yeah, no idea. It worked on the emulator, didn't on the phone. Just spot the differences from there... sorry there's not much else I can think of.

Comment: Have the same problem, hope anyone help us...

Comment: Hey @gerumato, I solved the problem using Android Studio. It's more elegant way, instead of copying .apk to the device/emulator.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Cordova 5.0.0 (but tried with earlier versions as well) on OSX with HTC Desire S running Android 4.1.2 as a target. I'm ready to create higher bounty but I have to wait until this one finishes.

Comment: Just installed all the Phonegap tools and run into this problem too. This answer solved it for me. What I don't understand is why this is not fixed by now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova "hello world" app won't display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I met the same problem ([Cordova "hello world" app won't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149970/cordova-hello-world-app-wont-display/30240425#30240425)) and found a way to pass through it (but I don't really understand the underlying causes).

Problem seemed to occur when installing the apk. On Cordova 5.0.0, adb commands to install the apk can be found at line 101 of file platforms\android\cordova\lib\device.js (and at line 311 of platforms\android\cordova\lib\emulator.js for cordova emulate android):

`adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"`

Current command returns to me: "Error: unknown option -d"!

**If you simply delete the "-d" option, applications run normally with cordova run android.**

## EDIT

> The `-d` is supposed to come directly after `adb` (as in `--device`) instead of after install. So you can just move it there instead of removing it.

Plus, [here is the opened issue on apache cordova issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8912)

Comment: Yes, this solved it! Sorry for the delay, I haven't been able to check this sooner. I'll try to look further into the problem but this clearly is the answer I needed.

Comment: -d is supposed to allow installation of app with lower version than already installed. it seems it's unsupported with some android versions (maybe before kitkat?)

Comment: I had to remove '-d' option to get it to work on Android 2.3 device.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a couple of things to check and be aware of, in case you didn't know:

- Your CLI version `cordova -v` won’t necessarily match the platform version `cordova platform`
- Your platform versions between the different platforms (if you have any) may not match.  For example, Android may have a different platform version than iOS.

If you've updated to the latest version of cordova-android sdk, please ensure you read through the releasenotes.md: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md

I'm not sure what SD is but I've installed my apps via

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

After comparing and checking your uploaded apk to your device, which I believe is easier to debug than the emulator, start up [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#issuingcommands) with [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#logcat):

```
adb -d logcat
```

If you prefer debugging with logcat through emulator, then:

```
adb -e logcat
```

There are extra debug flags to reduce the verbosity here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html. You'll need to adjust the filter spec to however you like, such as this: `adb logcat ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S`. I prefer to use `adb logcat *:D` to capture almost all debugging messages but reduce the verbosity slightly.

Hopefully, upon connection and startup of logcat you'll be able to catch what errors may be happening to cause your issue.

**EDIT:**
Here's another method to do device debugging via chrome browser developer tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

In general, here are the steps from the above link:

Requirements: Chrome 32 or later, USB cable to connect to Android device, browser debugging requires Android 4.0+, app debugging requires Android 4.4+

1. Enable USB debugging on the device: **Settings > Developer options**. If you have an Android 4.2+ device, the developer options are hidden by default. Click on **Settings > About phone** and tap **Build number** seven times.
2. In "Developer options", select **USB debugging** checkbox.
3. Click **OK** to confirm that you are turning on USB debugging.
4. Connect your device to your computer using the USB cable.
5. Open Chrome browser and in the search/address bar type **chrome://inspect**.
6. Click on the checkbox for **Discover USB devices**.
7. On your device, an alert prompt appears. Click **OK**.
8. The **chrome://inspect** page should now display your connected device. Click on the device's "inspect" link. Chrome developer tools should appear.

There is more information in the remote-debugging link above regarding live screencasting, proxy setup, port forwarding, and virtual host mapping.

Comment: Thank jojo. I'll check this as soon as I can and see where it leads me.

Answer (score 3):

For those using **Cordova 6.1.1** and having similar problem of not opening/installing the app, what worked for me was to run `ionic emulate android` once to open the android emulator with a home screen. Then, in another terminal window run again `ionic emulate android` which installed the application on the already opened emulator and everything worked normally.

Found similar problem in here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-works-correctly-ionic-emulate-android-just-displays-android-emulator-home-screen/53524/6

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Cordova Android v5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
edit **emulator.js** under **platforms\android\cordova\lib**

Go to line 311 and comment out the line

```
// return exec('adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r -d "' + apk_path + '"', os.tmpdir())
```

and paste new line

```
return exec('adb -s ' + resolvedTarget.target + ' install -r  "' + apk_path + '"', os.tmpdir())
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

for me this trick worked perfectly by removing the -d

but i had to install the apk manullay for the first time by transferring to phone and then i was able to run the app directly using ionic run android

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code in device.js and emulator.js didn't work for me (and in fact introduced an error where `cordova build android` wouldn't work anymore). My problem was completely different: I had two `<application>`s in my AndroidManifest.xml which is apparently not allowed.

Somewhere along the line I had added `<application android:debuggable="true" />` to my AndroidManifest.xml. However, that file *already* had an "application" element that looked like this:

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">`

So I added the "debuggable" line to the existing `<application>` (and removed the second `<application>`) like so:

`<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">`

After that I rebuilt using `cordova build android`, ran it successfully on my device with `cordova run android`, and then clapped my hands and scared my dog.

HOWEVER, even if this isn't your issue, here's how I discovered the problem: I followed the instructions in jojo's answer and ran `adb logcat` with my device connected. That terminal tab immediately filled up with interminable crap.

Then I opened a new terminal window that I could view at the same time, I took note of the latest timestamp in the logcat output, and I ran `cordova run android`. The screen filled up with more crap, and then once things calmed down I scrolled back up to my starting time and reviewed it line by line. Eventually I found my culprit:

`PackageParser: <manifest> has more than one <application>`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use simple -

```
cordova run anroid
```

If there is no conencted device it will show "No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator" and will launch the emulator.