# Ionic Application won't run on android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application that I try to run on the android platform. When I execute

> ionic run android

Or

> ionic emulate android

I have the following message:

> Total time: 0.814 secs
>   Built the following apk(s): 
>           /Volumes/DATA/apps/my_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
>   ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home

The application won't launch.

Here is the result of the ionic info command:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: 1.7.0 
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v4.4.5
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3 Build version 6D570
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956031/cordova-run-android-executes-fine-but-android-4-1-2-doesnt-start-the-app

Comment: @mablevj thanks for your response but I have already seen this issue, I don't have the same problem as I use cordova 6.4 and the **ionic emulate android** command doesn't show **LAUNCH SUCCESS** it pends right after **JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home**

Comment: Could you please add your system information by using cli command `ionic info`

Comment: @mablevj  please see the updates

Comment: Have you got any error messages like `Error: No emulator images (avds) found`.

Comment: No it pends right after **JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk‌​/Contents/Home** I don't have any warnings or errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130197/discussion-between-mablevj-and-nabila).

Answer (score 0):

Try remove android platform and reinstall :

```
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the platform, just go to this path file: `platforms/android/cordova/lib/device.js`

Comment this uninstall function line by changing this:

```
.return Adb.uninstall(resolvedTarget.target, pkgName)
    .then(function() {
        return Adb.install(resolvedTarget.target, apk_path, {replace: true});
});
```

to this:

```
//.return Adb.uninstall(resolvedTarget.target, pkgName)
//    .then(function() {
//         return Adb.install(resolvedTarget.target, apk_path, {replace: true});
//    });
```